# If $\Sigma \models \phi$, then for some finite $\Delta \subset\Sigma$, $\Delta \models \phi$.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

This is an easy consequence (Doets calls it Compactness Theorem (version 2))  in Kees Doets' Basic Model theory:

Let $\Sigma$ a set of sentences and $\phi$ a sentence.

If $\Sigma \models \phi$, then for some finite $\Delta \subset\Sigma$, $\Delta \models \phi$.

The proof by contradiction reads:

"If $\phi$ does not logically follow from some $\Delta \subset \Sigma$, then the set $\Sigma \cup \{\neg \phi\}$ is finitely satisfiable and therefore, by compactness, satisfiable."

How do we know that $\Sigma \cup \{\neg \phi\}$ is finitely satisfiable?

From the fact that $\phi$ does not logically follow from some $\Delta$, we know that $\neg \phi$ follows from every $\Delta \subset \Sigma$. But how does this imply that there's a model for every finite subset of the set of sentences?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, a quick comment. Your statement "From the fact that $\varphi$ does not logically follow from some $\Delta$, we know that $\neg\varphi$ follows from every $\Delta\subseteq \Sigma$." is incorrect: when $A$ is a set of sentences, "$A\not\models b$" is different from "$A\models\neg b$." We could have $b$ be *independent* of $A$ - that is, $A\not\models b$ and $A\not\models\neg b$.

What *is* true is that since $\varphi$ isn't entailed by any finite $\Delta\subseteq\Sigma$, $\neg\varphi$ must be *compatible with* every finite $\Delta\subseteq\Sigma$ in the sense that, for every $\Delta\subseteq\Sigma$, the set $\Delta\cup\{\neg\varphi\}$ will be satisfiable. (It's arguably more natural to say "consistent with" instead of "compatible with," but consistency is a *syntactic* property which isn't needed in this purely *semantic* question, so I want to avoid using language which might bring in confusion.)

---

This is in fact the crux of the problem!

Saying "$\Sigma\cup\{\neg\varphi\}$ is finitely satisfiable" just means "$\Delta\cup\{\neg\varphi\}$ is satisfiable for every finite $\Delta\subseteq\Sigma$." But "$\Delta\cup\{\neg\varphi\}$ is satisfiable" just means "there is some model of $\Delta\cup\{\neg\varphi\}$," which is to say $$\Delta\not\models\varphi$$ ("$\Delta\models\varphi$" means *exactly* "every model of $\Delta$ satisfies $\varphi$," which can't be true if there is some model of $\Delta\cup\{\neg\varphi\}$).

---

All that is to say that the statement "$\Sigma\cup\{\neg\varphi\}$ is finitely satisfiable" is equivalent to "For every finite $\Delta\subseteq\Sigma$, we have $\Delta\not\models\varphi$." But this latter statement is *precisely our hypothesis* "$\varphi$ does not logically follow from some [finite] $\Delta\subseteq\Sigma$!"

Note that the phrase "logically follow from" could confuse things here: it's meant in the *semantic* sense ($\models$), not the *syntactic* sense ($\vdash$).

Answer (score 5):

My intuition about this does not (directly) use contradiction. Rather, it follows from the soundness and completeness of first-order *logic*:

If $\Sigma\vDash\phi$, then there is a proof of $\Sigma\vdash\phi$ (completeness), and since that proof is a finite object it mentions at most finitely many of the axioms of $\Sigma$. Therefore the same proof proves $\Delta\vdash\phi$ for some finite $\Delta\subseteq\Sigma$, and thus $\Delta\vDash\phi$ (soundness).

Comment: To be fair, bringing the completeness theorem into a purely semantic problem is a bit overkill given that compactness can be proved without it.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I thought this is a purely syntactic problem, and bringing in models would make it semantic, now?

Comment: @Craig You have things backwards. "$\models$" is a purely semantic notion ($\Sigma\models\varphi$ iff every model of $\Sigma$ satisfies $\varphi$); "$\vdash$" is syntactic ($\Sigma\vdash\varphi$ iff there is a proof of $\varphi$ from $\Sigma$). Since the problem involves only "$\models$," it is (a priori) purely semantic.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ohhh, I thought that $\models$ was interpreted as logical deduction when used in relation to sets of formulas. That should clear everything up, thanks.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Well, this is the only way I could think about proving compactness either. But I'll admit to a strong bias in favor of proof theory ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm You're probably already familiar with this, but just in case: the semantic proof of compactness that really clicked for me - before the ultraproduct proof - was the fact that you can make Henkinization purely semantic. Let $\models_{fin}$ be the "finitary satisfaction relation," $A\models_{fin}b$ iff $D\models b$ for some finite $D\subseteq A$. We now proceed as usual, with $\models_{fin}$ in place of $\vdash$, and everything goes through basically unchanged. I also like this argument because it gives a(n interestingly, completely ahistorical) "story" for completeness: (cont'd)

Comment: in light of the coincidence of $\models$ with $\models_{fin}$, since the latter is finitary it's reasonable to hope that it is in fact computably enumerable. To find an appropriate $\vdash$, we now just look carefully through the proof that $\models_{fin}$ is all of $\models$, and each time we use a property of $\models_{fin}$ we get a corresponding proof rule. Of course, this isn't how it happened, but it's a natural enough story that I found it very helpful in learning the proof theoretic side of things: that the semantic result led naturally to the syntactic conjecture and ultimate success.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Uhm, but ... isn't the fact that $\vDash$ coincides with $\vDash_{\rm fin}$ exactly what the compactness theorem states? If you're using that fact in your proof, then what is it you're _proving_?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Comment 2 happens *after* comment 1. The "in light of" is *following* the proof of the compactness theorem above. My point is that, having proved compactness, it's now natural to look for a proof notion making the completeness theorem true; and having proved compactness specifically in the Henkin style, this becomes very straightforward.

Comment: Everything after "I also like" is not part of the proof of compactness, but an afterthought.

Comment: @NoahSchweber ah, that's a very nice way of thinking about things!! out of curiosity, do you ever teach the compactness theorem using this $\models_{\text{fin}}$ proof? I very much like the idea of using it to motivate the definition of $\vdash$

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Yup, that tends to be exactly how I explain it. So far I've had good results, but to be fair I've only taught rather limited audiences with this so far.

Answer (score 1):

Every $\Delta$ finite have $\Delta\vDash\lnot\varphi$, so every model of $\Delta$ is a model of $\Delta\cup\{\lnot\varphi\}$, and there is a model for every $\Delta$, namely, the model of $\Sigma$

Comment: So does Doets assume that $\Sigma$ has a model?

Comment: If there is no model to $\Sigma$, there is finite deduction sequence that proves contradiction, take $\Delta$ be all the elements of $\Sigma$ that appear in that sequence and you got a finite subset of $\Sigma$ that proves $\varphi$

Comment: @Holo "If there is no model to $\Sigma$, there is finite deduction sequence that proves contradiction" This uses the completeness theorem, which is overkill here.

Comment: @NoahSchweber that is true.. but this is the easiest way to look at this(at least the easiest from the ways I know)

Comment: @Holo I disagree - $\vdash$ isn't needed at all, this is just a direct application of the basic definition of $\models$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I don't mean that we need $\vdash$, but I prefer to use it, I will read your answer now, you have more experience in this field than me, so it is likely you are correct, if so I would love to learn from this.