# Understanding the method for the proof of compactness theorem

Tags: logic, proof-writing, proof-explanation, compactness, model-theory

In [Sets, Logic, Computation](https://slc.openlogicproject.org/), the compactness theorem is stated as follows:

> For any sentences $\Gamma$ and $A$, the following holds:
>
> 1. $\Gamma\models A$ iff there is some finite $\Gamma_0\subseteq\Gamma$ s.t. $\Gamma_0\models A$.
> 2. $\Gamma$ is satisfiable iff for any finite $\Gamma_0\subseteq\Gamma$, $\Gamma_0$ is satisfiable.

I have an impression that properties 1 and 2 are logically equivalent, i.e. property 1 holds iff property 2 holds.

However, it appears to me that the textbook proves properties 1 and 2 separately. The proof for property 2 presented in the textbook does not assume property 1 holds. I also found a proof for property 1 without assuming property 2 holds.

So since properties 1 and 2 can be proved independently, it trivially follows that property 1 holds iff property 2 holds? It is analogous to saying that the natural number $n=2$ is both (i) $n$ is even and (ii) $n$ is prime, and hence (i) iff (ii).

Is there an alternative proof for "property 1 iff property 2" that does not involve proving 1 and 2 independently?

Comment: To make sense of saying that two results are equivalent after you've proved both of them, in a way that's not completely trivial, we could to prove the equivalence in a weaker theory than what we used to prove the results themselves. In this case, we might ask if we can prove $1 \iff 2$ without using the axiom of choice.

Comment: Hi John. I'm looking at the book [here](https://slc.openlogicproject.org/slc-screen.pdf). Upon a quick skim, I can see proofs related to compactness at theorems 12.23 and 12.31. It seems to me that in both cases, all that's provided is a proof of (2). Can you point to where (1) is proved independently of (2)? You're right that the two forms are very similar and can be deduced from one another. Either can also be proved as a fairly easy consequence of completeness. It seems to me that the book considers this so obvious that it only proves one and leaves you to prove the other.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Right, the proof for (1) is not mentioned at all. I found a simple proof myself without (2).

Comment: OK, we're on the same page. From "it appears to me that the textbook proves properties 1 and 2 separately" it seemed to me that you had the impression that the textbook's authors had given two separate proofs, which would be a bit odd. You can indeed prove (1) either by modifying the argument for (2) (translate $\models$ into $\vdash$), or by directly using (2) and the fact that $\Gamma \models A$ iff $\Gamma \cup \{\lnot A\}$ is not satisfiable. You can get (2) from (1) by using the fact that $\Gamma$ is satisfiable iff $\Gamma \not\models \bot$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, statements 1. and 2. are equivalent. Each one can be easily derived from the other.

Note that in the [book](https://slc.openlogicproject.org/) you cited, there is no proof at all of 1. (I guess the authors think it is obvious to derive 1. from 2.), but there are two independent proofs of 2.

The fact that 2. implies 1. is already proved and discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3031577/288417), using purely semantic methods (actually, it proves that 2. implies the left-to-right implication in 1., which is the hard task. The right-to-left implication of 1. is trivial, as it immediately follows from the definition of logical consequence $\models$).

Now, let us prove that 1. implies 2. Since 2. is an equivalence statement, we must show the left-to-right and right-to-left implications in 2.

- Left-to-right: Let $\Gamma$ be a satisfiable set of formulas. This means there is a structure $\mathcal{M}$ such that: $\mathcal{M} \models B$ for every $B \in \Gamma$. Hence, $\mathcal{M} \models \Gamma_0$ for every finite $\Gamma_0 \subseteq \Gamma$. Therefore, every finite $\Gamma_0 \subseteq \Gamma$ is satisfiable.
- Right-to-left (proof by contraposition): Let $\Gamma$ be an unsatisfiable set of formulas. Then, $\Gamma \neq \emptyset$ (otherwise satisfiability of $\Gamma$ would be [vacuously true](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)) and so there is $A \in \Gamma$. Thus, $\Gamma \models \lnot A$ (vacuously, since there is no model of $\Gamma$). By 1. (left-to-right), there is a finite $\Gamma_0 \subseteq \Gamma$ such that $\Gamma_0 \models \lnot A$, that is, $\mathcal{M} \models \lnot A$ for every model $\mathcal{M}$ of $\Gamma_0$. Hence, $\mathcal{M} \not\models A$ for every model $\mathcal{M}$ of $\Gamma_0$. Therefore, the finite set of formulas $\Gamma_0 \cup \{A\} \subseteq \Gamma$ is unsatisfiable. $\qquad\square$

Some remarks:

- The left-to-right implication in 2. is trivial, it immediately follows from the definition of satisfiability, without appealing to 1.
- The proof of the right-to-left implication in 2. is not trivial and it crucially exploits 1. (left-to-right).
- The above proof that 1. implies 2. is completely semantic, and in particular, it never uses the completeness theorem.

Comment: Hmm, in the proof of 1. implies 2., in right-to-left case, I am suspicious with the $\Gamma\models\lnot A$ part. Based on my understanding, sentence $A\in\Gamma$ is dependent on which model $\mathcal M$ is used. After fixing a particular sentence $A\in\Gamma$, it might not be necessarily true that $\mathcal M\not\models A$ for all models $\mathcal M$...

Comment: Oh wait, I take back what I said. Even if $\mathcal M\not\models A$ is false, $\Gamma\models\lnot A$ still holds. I think it is more clearer if you write "Fix some $A\in\Gamma$. Then, $\Gamma\models\lnot A$."

Comment: @JohnDavies - Indeed. This point is subtle (it's the only tricky part of the proof). I rewrote the argument (the beginning of the proof of the right-to-left implication in 2.) to make it clearer. My precedent formulation of the argument wasn't wrong, but slightly convoluted and misleading.